# human visual: relation of Distance and DPI

Tags: computational-geometry, 2d, pixel-graphics, pixels, human-vision

I was told that human's visual sharpness is 60 pixels per degree. As such, pixel per inch is approximately given by:

```
PPI = 1/ (Distance * tg((1/60*pi/180) )
```

Is this formula fully correct? (I saw similar, but slightly different versions). How is this formula derived? Maybe some step by step description?

Comment: Could you either include a link to the source of this formula, or define what the terms in it refer to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to a review by Legge & Bigelow the arc or degrees of visual angle ($\alpha$) is,

$$
\alpha = 57.3 \times S/D,
$$

where S is height of object and D is distance to object. [1] $S/D$ is the small angles approximation of $2 \times arctan(S/2D)$ which follows form geometry.

[image]

**Image 1**: the equation comes straight from trigonometric definitions.

Since humans continuously scan the page with the fovea, small angles assumption is a good approximation for entire pages. The factor $57.3$ is simply $180/\pi$ or conversion form radians to angles.

So given that we do not know the nature of $tg$, then its hard to say. Looks a bit fishy, but if tg is some sort of inversion of S then its plausible.

[1] G. Legge & C Bigelow. 2011. Jornal of vision. [Does print size matter for reading? A review of findings from vision science and typography](http://jov.arvojournals.org/article.aspx?articleid=2191906).